# Will this Observable create a memory leak?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Will this Observable create a memory leak?
becuase every time you run it, it will keep the initial select stream open?!?!

```
return this.store.select(store => store.appDb.appBaseUrl)                          
            .mergeMap(url => {
                return this.http.get(url)
                    .debug('received ' + url)
                    .map(res => res.json())
            })
```

and if so, will adding a take(1) fix it?

```
return this.store.select(store => store.appDb.appBaseUrl)                          
               .take(1) // <--------------- stop after 1?
               .mergeMap(url => {
                return this.http.get(url)
                    .debug('received ' + url)
                    .map(res => res.json())
            })
```

tx Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply having an hot observable `this.store.select` does not immediately imply that you have a memory leak. It is your task to store a reference to your subscription on that observable and dispose of it when done.

I find it helpful to annotate my streams with `.take(X)` as the last thing i do when i know how many elements i expect because this will make the stream dispose automatically after emitting the expected amount.

```
return this.store.select(store => store.appDb.appBaseUrl)                          
  .mergeMap(url => this.http.get(url)
    .debug('received ' + url)
    .map(res => res.json())
  )
  .take(1)
```

Comment: I see, well the subscription is managed by the effects library.. but I do call this action multiple times..